# SQL Server: CASE WHEN with temp tables syntax errroring out

Tags: sql, string, if-statement, replace, case

The logic I'm trying to implement is as follows: Replace certain strings with other strings for a specific column.

Leave string values that do not need to be replaced as their original values.

```
   SELECT * INTO #df_ERA4_a_temp 
            CASE WHEN [REQMNT] = 'A CHEC' THEN 'A CHECK'   
                 WHEN [REQMNT] = 'A-12' THEN 'A12'
                 WHEN [REQMNT] = 'A-9' THEN 'A9'
                 WHEN [REQMNT] = 'ADS-B' THEN 'ADSB' 
                 WHEN [REQMNT] = 'ADWK' THEN 'ADWORK'
                 WHEN [REQMNT] = 'ALI-W' THEN 'ALI-WRK'
                 ELSE [REQMNT]
            END  
    FROM #df_ERA4_a
```

Error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 129
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Comment: Missing select before case

Answer (score 0):

See if that helps

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN [REQMNT] = 'A CHEC' THEN 'A CHECK'   
                     WHEN [REQMNT] = 'A-12' THEN 'A12'
                     WHEN [REQMNT] = 'A-9' THEN 'A9'
                     WHEN [REQMNT] = 'ADS-B' THEN 'ADSB' 
                     WHEN [REQMNT] = 'ADWK' THEN 'ADWORK'
                     WHEN [REQMNT] = 'ALI-W' THEN 'ALI-WRK'
                     ELSE [REQMNT] END, 
     * INTO #df_ERA4_a_temp                
        FROM #df_ERA4_a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * INTO #df_ERA4_a_temp
FROM
(SELECT CASE WHEN [REQMNT] = 'A CHEC' THEN 'A CHECK'   
             WHEN [REQMNT] = 'A-12' THEN 'A12'
             WHEN [REQMNT] = 'A-9' THEN 'A9'
             WHEN [REQMNT] = 'ADS-B' THEN 'ADSB' 
             WHEN [REQMNT] = 'ADWK' THEN 'ADWORK'
             WHEN [REQMNT] = 'ALI-W' THEN 'ALI-WRK'
             ELSE [REQMNT]
        END  
FROM #df_ERA4_a) a
```

Comment: This is the error I get: Invalid object name '#df_ERA5_a_temp'.

Comment: @PineNuts0 - I got to know you are trying to select into temp, I modified the query